# Obtaining links from webpage with python - better alternative to Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, hyperlink

I've been browsing around quite a lot on the matter and got something to work for my problem, but was wondering if there was a better solution.

In particular, I need to get all links to pdf files from a webpage - say, for example: http://stock.walmart.com/investors/financial-information/annual-reports-and-proxies/default.aspx

I initially tried with something simple as (I am working with Python3):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import os

base_url = 'http://stock.walmart.com/investors/financial-information/annual-reports-and-proxies/default.aspx'
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"}

r = requests.get(url=base_url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
links = soup.findAll('a', href=True)
for tag in links:
    tag['href'] = urllib.parse.urljoin(base_url, tag['href'])

    if os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(tag['href']))[1] == '.pdf':
        print(tag['href'])
```

But that does not do as I am missing all the links to PDFs. I am not an expert on the subject, but reading around it seems it's because they are rendered dynamically with JavaScript or obtained through a subsequent POST request.

Therefore, I tried a second approach, with Selenium:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')  
driver.get(url)

elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")

print([link for link in url_list if link[-4:].lower() == '.pdf'])
```

That works, but it looks quite heavy to me for what seems an easy task. Therefore:

1. Am I missing something in the first approach, that could make it work? A friend recommended simply using `wget` from command line, which seems to work and finds all pdf links (!!), therefore there might be an easy way of doing this...
2. If we really need to use a webdriver, what's the lightest alternative? I would not want to use Chrome and open up a browser window - I was reading about PhantomJS but not sure
3. How can we deal with re-directs? would the second approach take care of them?

In general, any other tip for accomplishing the task is more than welcome. Should I look into scrapy? Or would that present the same problem?

Thanks much.

Comment: Are you looking for a dedicated solution for this particular web page, or something that will "always work"? (spoiler: the latter one does not exist :)). Looking into what Chrome does while loading the page might help. I see a call to http://stock.walmart.com/Services/FinancialReportService.svc/GetFinancialReportList in there that looks quite promising, and that you could easily run with the requests and json libraries alone.

Comment: Ideally I was looking for a general solution, as I'd have other web pages similar to that one :) Also because, as mentioned, with `wget` I can get something rudimentary that works - so my hope was to get something similar in Python

Comment: Hm, afaik wget does not interpret JavaScript. How does wget work on the particular page you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

## Selenium...

A truly general solution will have to account for the fact that many modern webpages use JavaScript to render their content. As a result, such content will be inaccessible to any tool or library, such as `wget` or `requests`, that lacks a JavaScript runtime. Needing a JavaScript runtime, then, effectively means needing a browser, and Selenium is the most robust way to control a browser.

## ... with headless Chrome...

As for a “lightweight” approach, PhantomJS is certainly an option, but its support and subsequent value have waned as major browsers such as Chrome have begun to provide increasingly reliable headless operation. At this point, I would strongly recommend headless Chrome over PhantomJS.

## ... and (as a bonus) Capybara

While Selenium provides you with the essential tools to control a browser, it leaves the handling of a modern asynchronous web application as an exercise for the reader. What if, for example, it takes a while for the content on a page to load? Selenium requires that you repeatedly and explicitly manage this.

[capybara-py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/capybara-py) helps with this by providing a layer atop Selenium that, among other things, transparently synchronizes your interactions, whether you’re loading a page or filling in form fields or clicking links and buttons:

```py
import capybara
from capybara.dsl import page
import re

@capybara.register_driver("selenium_chrome_headless")
def init_selenium_chrome_headless_driver(app):
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from capybara.selenium.driver import Driver

    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    return Driver(app, browser="chrome", chrome_options=chrome_options)

capybara.current_driver = "selenium_chrome_headless"

page.visit(url)

links = page.find_all("link",

                      # Match only URLs ending in ".pdf"
                      href=re.compile(r"\.pdf$"),

                      # Assuming you expect, and would like to wait
                      # for, at least one PDF link on the page
                      minimum=1)

urls = [link["href"] for link in links]
```

Comment: Thanks - very keen to try this. However, after a pip install capybara, I have an error: 'no module named 'amazon_wrapper'', which does not seem available through pip. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Install `capybara-py`.

Answer (score 0):

Two options that I consider "good" approaches:

1. Look at the network tab in the dev tools of your browser when the page loads. Find out what request is returning the pdf links, and mimic that request with the "requests" or urllib libraries. Fast, efficient.
2. If you are not comfortable enough with http requests and are not willing to take the couple hours to become so, use selenium with a browser (Chrome is the easiest) in headless mode to render the page with javascript included and scrape as desired.